# Where do I find the log for an xamrin android archive upload

Tags: android, xamarin

My attempt to upload an xamarin archive failed, and it says to examine the log for details.
Where do I find the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help tab at the top of visual studio.

Help > xamarin > Open Logs